# In Android, can you delete an application from another application?

Tags: android

If I have two applications loaded on an Android device, are there calls I can make in one that will delete the other one? I am looking for something to delete apps in a fashion similar to how I can launch an app from another.

I thought this may be possible through the Intent/Activity interactions but it doesn't seem possible. This seems like something that may not be allowed for obvious reasons but wanted to check anyways.

Follow up question, can an application remove itself?

Comment: No. Not without root, and even then not like you can launch an app.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot complete the removal without user approval, but you can use an intent to bring up a screen where they can confirm the removal:

```
<manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
 ...
</manifest>
```

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"some.package.to.remove");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are apps like quick uninstaller that speed up the delete process, you'll probably need to find an Intent that deletes the app, because the user still needs to have the final say over this.