# Can you delete an application from another application?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Like this article,

[In Android, can you delete an application from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412588/in-android-can-you-delete-an-application-from-another-application)

Can you delete an application from another application **on windows phone 7 or 8**? (including 
enterprise features)

and I have a **same question with iOS**. I know that enterprise features provide installing another application via url. but what about "uninstalls", does it possible ?

Comment: You certainly can do it with a jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrt. to enterprise features, you can install packages, as well as view status of installed packages (installed, percent installed, pending install), plus various properties like app icon etc. But still no API for uninstalling these packages. See InstallationManager API on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 6):

No, Windows Phone will not allow your app to access any files outside your own app's sandbox.  You can't delete other apps or even access their data.  Allowing an app to do so would be a huge security problem.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, it is not possible to delete an app from another application. Apple will never allow that in a normal device. I am not sure about jail broken iPhones. User has to manually delete an application for normal devices. Looks like even Windows phones wont allow this.