# How i can delete another app data in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

When i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear $packagename"); ,my app stopped so use this in a thread but this is not working(i think thread stopped.

I only intend to delete the data of a program in case of an emergency by the user's choice, of course, this is done in the service.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412588/in-android-can-you-delete-an-application-from-another-application)

Comment: When I do this, when I start the internet, it will show me a confirmation page to delete the program. I want to get permission in advance so that whenever the user wants, I can delete the data of the program or myself without confirmation.Is it possible for me to display the uninstall dialog now and if it is approved, I can start the dialog whenever I want? It seems like a ridiculous question.

Comment: each package has special places allocated for its data which is usually protected from tamper by other applications without necessary manifest permissions. it is not a kotlin issue, but a safeguard put in place by android. you could do this from ADB, but i highly doubt you can do this without using PackageManager especially just by trying to run a script from system shell. the reason your program is crashing might be due to $packagename returning nothing due to lack of permission and causing NullPointerException

Comment: For this, system apps use the CLEAR_APP_DATA permission, so I cannot use this permission in my application. Is there no other permission? Can I do this with SYSTEM_POLICY_MANAGER?In addition, I don't have any problem with Magepz and other work, I even looked for a way that the user confirms the dialog of uninstalling the app in advance and I can execute the command when I want to.